# Deleting multiple rows of a table with Jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to be able to delete checkbox-selected rows but when I click on "Delete Selected", both the table on the web page and MySQL database stay unchanged. How do I get the selected rows from both the web page and the database to be deleted?

Edit: I'm now able to delete the rows but only the first row, despite selecting more than one checkbox, or selecting another checkbox not on the first row. Also, if I want to delete another entry, I will have to first refresh the page before deleting another one.

**datatable.php**

```
<div class="row well">
    <a type="button" class="delete_all btn btn-primary pull-right">Delete Selected</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function($)
{

function create_html_table (tbl_data) {

tbl +='<table>';
tbl +='<thead>';
tbl +='<tr>';

tbl +='<th rowspan="3"><input type="checkbox" id="master"></th>';
// More table headers
tbl +='</tr>';
tbl +='</thead>';

tbl +='<tbody>';

          $.each(tbl_data, function(index, val) 
            {   
                var row_id = val['row_id'];

                //loop through ajax row data
                tbl +='<tr id="row" row_id="'+row_id+'">';

                    tbl +='<td><input type="checkbox" class="sub_chk"></td>';
                    tbl +='<td>'+(index + 1)+'</td>';
                    tbl +='<td><div col_name="filename">'+val['filename']+'</div></td>';
                    // More data
                tbl +='</tr>';
             });

tbl +='</tbody>';
tbl +='</table>';
}

var ajax_url = "<?php echo APPURL;?>/ajax.php" ;

// Multi-select
$(document).on("click","#master", function(e) {

if($(this).is(':checked',true))  
{
    $(".sub_chk").prop('checked', true);  
}  
else  
{  
    $(".sub_chk").prop('checked',false);  
}  
});

//Delete selected rows
$(document).on('click', '.delete_all', function(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var ele_this = $('#row') ;
    var row_id = ele_this.attr('row_id');

    var allVals = [];
    $(".sub_chk:checked").each(function()
    {    
    allVals.push(row_id);
    });

    if(allVals.length <=0)  
    {  
        alert("Please select row.");  
    }

    else {

    var data_obj=
    {
        call_type:'delete_row_entry',
        row_id:row_id,
    };  

    ele_this.html('<p class="bg-warning">Please wait....deleting your entry</p>')

    $.post(ajax_url, data_obj, function(data) 
    { 
        var d1 = JSON.parse(data); 
        if(d1.status == "error")
        {
            var msg = ''
            + '<h3>There was an error while trying to add your entry</h3>'
            +'<pre class="bg-danger">'+JSON.stringify(data_obj, null, 2) +'</pre>'
            +'';


        }
        else if(d1.status == "success")
        {
            ele_this.closest('tr').css('background','red').slideUp('slow');              
        }
    });

    }   

});

});

</script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
//--->Delete row entry  > start
if(isset($_POST['call_type']) && $_POST['call_type'] =="delete_row_entry")

{   

$row_id = app_db()->CleanDBData($_POST['row_id']);   

$q1 = app_db()->select("select * from data where row_id='$row_id'");
if($q1 > 0) 
{
    //found a row to be deleted
    $strTableName = "data";

    $array_where = array('row_id' => $row_id);

    //Call it like this:
    app_db()->Delete($strTableName,$array_where);

    echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 'success', 
        'msg' => 'deleted entry', 
    ));
    die();
}    
}
//--->Delete row entry  > end
```

I've seen other similar SO questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100993/deleting-multiple-selected-table-rows-using-only-javascript) but I don't think it is applicable to my code.

My output:

[image]

Comment: it seems that by using `var ele_this = $(this);` in the click function, your `ele_this` is the delete button, not the checkboxes. So that firstly, you don't get the checkboxes `row_id` but the button's one which is undefined (you should get `row_id` inside the `each`). Then when trying to delete the rows, the same way `ele_this` is still the button, so `closest` will do unexpected things. You have to re-think this part too.

Comment: I've edited the code slightly and now I'm able to delete rows, but only one at a time, even if I select more than one checkbox. Any ideas on how to delete more than 1 row at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you have to select the good elements the right way. For example, an HTML `id` must be unique, so giving all your elements the same `id="row"` won't work. Using your class will be enough. Then you have to consider that `each` will execute the function separately for all your selected elements, so that if you want to do things for each element, all the code must be inside.

I optimized a little your code by getting rid of `allVals` variable, if its only goal is to test if rows have been selected, you can directly test `.length` on your selection. I renamed variables so that it's more clear which is what.

Also it's not very clear in the question if the "Please wait....deleting your entry" text should appear in the button or in each row, i assumed it was in the button, and it will help you differentiate all elements from how they are selected.

```
//Delete selected rows
$(document).on('click', '.delete_all', function(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();

    //'click' is called on the button, so 'this' here will be the button
    var button = $(this) ;

    var checked_checkboxes = $(".sub_chk:checked");

    if(checked_checkboxes.length <=0)  
    {  
        alert("Please select row.");  
    }
    else {

        button.html('<p class="bg-warning">Please wait....deleting your entry</p>');

        //next code will be executed for each checkbox selected:
        checked_checkboxes.each(function(){
            var checkbox = $(this);
            var row_id = checkbox.attr('row_id');
            var data_obj=
            {
                call_type: 'delete_row_entry',
                row_id: row_id,
            };

            $.post(ajax_url, data_obj, function(data) 
            { 
                var d1 = JSON.parse(data); 
                if(d1.status == "error")
                {
                    var msg = ''
                    + '<h3>There was an error while trying to add your entry</h3>'
                    +'<pre class="bg-danger">'+JSON.stringify(data_obj, null, 2) +'</pre>'
                    +'';

                    //you still have to do something with your message, keeping in mind that a separate message will be generated for each separate $.post (one is emitted for each checked checkbox)
                }
                else if(d1.status == "success")
                {
                    checkbox.closest('tr').css('background','red').slideUp('slow');              
                }
            });
        });
    }   

});
```